# Adding 2 different widgets on single window GTK+

Tags: c++, gtk

I want to add 2 Widgets on same window one is of type `gtk_drawing_area_new ();` for using Cairo and other is of `fixed` to add some buttons.

Is there anyway I can do this on same Window? I'm new to GTK+.

Comment: I know I'm doing everything wrong only thing I want is to use Cairo and also use simple GTK functions like `button` and `layout` along with cairo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a GtkContainer subclass such as `GtkHBox`, `GtkVBox` or `GtkGrid`

```
GtkWidget *hbox = gtk_hbox_new (FALSE, 0);
GtkWidget *drawingArea = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Button");

gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), hbox);

gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (hbox), drawingArea, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (hbox), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_widget_show_all (window);
```

You can see all the standard containers that are available here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#GtkContainer.object-hierarchy